# maxwell stress tensor mathematical method

Tags: physics, tensors

It has been a while since I touched tensor so some assistance would certainly be appreciated.

The maxwell stress tensor is given as: 
$T_{ij}=\epsilon _{0}\left ( E_{i}E_{j}\frac{1}{2}\delta _{ij}E^{2} \right )+\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}\left ( B_{i}B_{j}-\frac{1}{2}\delta _{ij}B^{2} \right )
$

For i=j=x,

$T_{xx}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon _{0}\left ( E_{x}^{2}+E_{y}^{2}+E_{z}^{2}+ \right )+\frac{1}{2\mu_{0}}\left ( B_{x}^{2}+B_{y}^{2}+B_{z}^{2} \right )$

How did this came to be? When I did direct 'substitution' of i=j=x, I was not able to arrive at the final expression.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that the [Einstein Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Introduction) $T_{ii}$ is short-hand for $\sum_{i=1}^3T_{ii}$.

Recall that the Kronecker Delta $\delta_{ij}$ is given by

$$\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&,i=j\\\\0&,i\ne j\end{cases}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3T_{ii}&=\sum_{i=1}^3\left(\epsilon _{0}\left ( E_{i}E_{i}-\frac{1}{2}\delta _{ii}E^{2} \right )+\frac{1}{\mu_{0}}\left ( B_{i}B_{i}-\frac{1}{2}\delta _{ii}B^{2} \right )\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(E_1^2+E_2^2+E_3^2)+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\left(B_1^2+B_2^2+B_3^2\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Should there also be -$\frac{E^{2}}{2}$-$\frac{E^{2}}{2}$-$\frac{E^{2}}{2}$?

Comment: Note that $E^2=E_1^2+E_2^2+E_3^2$. Therefore, we have  $$(E_1^2+E_2+E_3^2)-\frac12(E_1^2+E_2^2+E_3^2)=\frac12(E_1^2+E_2^2+E_3^2)$$